# How to compress image size, while saving to folder ? [ c# asp.net ]

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am in a situation that I need to validate image size to a specific range  (between 20 kb to 40kb).

```
public bool SaveImage(string ImgStr, string ImgName, string folder)
    {
        try
        {
            String path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(folder);

            if (ImgStr.Contains("data:image/png;base64,"))
            {
                ImgStr = ImgStr.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
            }

            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path); //Create directory if it doesn't exist
            }

            string imageName = ImgName;

            //set the image path
            string imgPath = Path.Combine(path, imageName);

            byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ImgStr);

            File.WriteAllBytes(imgPath, imageBytes);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception _ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Using this function I need to save the image in between 20kb to 40kb size range. Image is in base 64 format and I am unable to compress the image in that size. The function runs on a loop so no way I can't validate it by filling in an image box. Also, I have to stick with image width and height as same the original image

How can I compress a base64 image to a file size ??

Comment: Did you make a copypaste error in your If ... jpg ? If your string contains jpg you try and replace png

Comment: @CaiusJard actually I don't remember why I did that, `"data:image/png;base64,"` part didn't seem that necessary cz the image is downloading just fine as I wanted.. I am stuck on this size validation.

Comment: How do you intend on keeping the original height and width while at the same time reducing the image's size in bytes. While that's likely possible for a small subset of images (redrawing with different color depths/quality/aliasing tricks) I doubt it can be generalized

Answer (score 1):

Given that you can't vary your image dimensions..

..For a PNG, you don't have a lot of choice because it's not a compression that can be varied but there are tricks you can pull with the structure of the image to change the compression outcome. See, for example, what the people at https://tinypng.com did (no affiliation)

..For JPEG it's somewhat easier; you can dial the compression level up and down to achieve your target size. There isn't an exact science that can tell you what the final output size will be, but it usually follows a curve if you want to come up with a formula that would allow you to compress at e.g. quality 1, and then make an esitmate of what level would get you to 20-40kb based on the resulting size at 1. See https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-comparison-of-jpeg-compression-levels-and-recompression/ or do your own tests at various levels on representative images and see what sort of sizes you get. If you have CPU resource spare/this isn't a high use system you might find it adequate to just have a "compress original, check size, recompress original at different quality, check again" loop that just keeps saving a new version at ever increasing(decreasing, depending how it represents) quality factors til it hits the desired size range

Answer (score 0):

I end up using the following code.. but still no way I can validate the size to 20-40kb. and there is another issue .. image size between 40-50kb becomes less than 20kb so no way I can stick with the minimum size like wanted.

```
 byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ImgStr);

     int length = imageBytes.Length;

            if (length > 45800)
            {
                var jpegQuality = 99;
                Byte[] outputBytes;
                System.Drawing.Image image;
                using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
                {
                    image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(inputStream);
                    var jpegEncoder = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders()
                      .First(c => c.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);
                    var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
                    encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, jpegQuality);

                    using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        image.Save(outputStream, jpegEncoder, encoderParameters);
                        outputBytes = outputStream.ToArray();
                    }
                }
                imageBytes = outputBytes;
            }

            File.WriteAllBytes(imgPath, imageBytes);
```